# Split a sequence into two alternating sequences

Tags: scala, collections, split

I would like to split a sequence of size > 2 into alternating sequences like this:

```
def splitAlt(s: Seq[Char]): (Seq[Char], Seq[Char]) = ???

splitAlt(Nil)  // raise an exception
splitAlt("a")  // raise an exception  
splitAlt("ab") // (Seq('a'), Seq('b'))
splitAlt("abc") // (Seq('a', 'c'), Seq('b'))
```

I found an elegant [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293402/521070) with `grouped` and `transpose` I'd like to use.
Unfortunately it works only i fthe input sequence has even size.
How would you modify that solution to work for input of any size ?

Do you have a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very straightforward solution:

```
def splitAlt[T](s: Seq[T]): (Seq[T], Seq[T]) = {
  val (fsts, snds) = s.zipWithIndex.partition { case (x, i) => i % 2 == 0 }
  (fsts.map(_._1), snds.map(_._1))
}

splitAlt("")      // -> (Seq(), Seq())
splitAlt("a")     // -> (Seq(a), Seq())
splitAlt("ab")    // -> (Seq(a), Seq(b))
splitAlt("abc")   // -> (Seq(a, c), Seq(b))
splitAlt("abcd")  // -> (Seq(a, c), Seq(b, d))
splitAlt("abcde") // -> (Seq(a, c, e), Seq(b, d))
```

I claim it's elegant because:

- it doesn't throw an exception, it just returns empty sequences;
- it works for sequences of any type, not just characters;
- it works for sequences of any length;
- it traverses the sequence only once.

**Update:** this is a generalization for an arbitrary number of groups:

```
def splitGen[T](xs: Seq[T], n: Int): Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  val groups =
    xs.zipWithIndex
      .groupBy { case (x, i) => i % n }
      .mapValues { vs => vs.map(_._1) }
  0 until n map groups
}

splitGen("abcdefg", 1)  // -> Seq(Seq(a, b, c, d, e, f, g))
splitGen("abcdefg", 2)  // -> Seq(Seq(a, c, e, g), Seq(b, d, f))
splitGen("abcdefg", 3)  // -> Seq(Seq(a, d, g), Seq(b, e), Seq(c, f))
splitGen("abcdefg", 4)  // -> Seq(Seq(a, e), Seq(b, f), Seq(c, g), Seq(d))
splitGen("abcdefg", 5)  // -> Seq(Seq(a, f), Seq(b, g), Seq(c), Seq(d), Seq(e))
```

You can generalize the `grouped`+`transpose` solution by padding the original sequence for the length to be just right and then unpadding the result, but it requires you to take care of some special cases:

```
def splitGen[T](xs: Seq[T], n: Int): Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  /* Pad */
  val paddedLength: Int = math.ceil(xs.length / n.toDouble).toInt * n
  val padded: Seq[T] =
    if (xs.isEmpty) xs
    else            xs.padTo(paddedLength, xs.head)

  /* Transpose */
  val transposed = padded.grouped(n).toList.transpose

  /* Unpad */
  if (paddedLength == xs.length) transposed
  else transposed.zipWithIndex.map { case (row, i) =>
    if (i < xs.length % n) row
    else                   row.init
  }
```

}

Comment: I agree it's probably better to return empty sequences if the input size < 2.

Comment: One more problem is that it's hard to generalize this solution for splitting the input into 3, 4, 5 and more subsequences. The generalization was not a  part of the question. I will probably ask about it separately.

Comment: @Michael: I added a comparison of the generalized solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach based on the `grouped` + `transpose` solution.

```
def splitAlt[T](s: Seq[T]) = {
    s.grouped(2).toList.map(p => Seq(p.headOption, p.tail.headOption)).transpose.map(_.flatten)
}
```

Basically, it turns the inner `List[T]` returned by `grouped` into `List[Option[T]]` with exactly 2 elements, as `transpose` requires all collections to be of equal size.

Noted that this returns a nested list rather than a pair of lists. We'd need some special care for the less-than-2-elements cases if we are to turn the results into tuple, so for the sake of 'elegance' I keep it like this.

Comment: Thanks. Nice but a bit too complicated to my taste. Hope to find a simpler solution.