# Walk through a list split function in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, split, fold

This is a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974560/split-a-sequence-into-two-alternating-sequences).

I am trying to understand the list splitting example in Haskell from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Blow_your_mind):

```
foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[])
```

I can read Haskell and know what `foldr` is but don't understand this code. Could you walk me through this code and explain it in more details ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s try running this function on a sample input list, say `[1,2,3,4,5]`:

1. We start with `foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [1,2,3,4,5]`. Here `a` is the first element of the list, and `(x,y)` start out as `([],[])`, so `(a:y,x)` returns `([1],[])`.
2. The next element of the input list is `a = 2`, and `(x,y) = ([1],[])`, so `(a:y,x) = ([2],[1])`. Note that the order of the lists has swapped. Each iteration will swap the lists again; however, the next element of the input list will always be added to the first list, which is how the splitting works.
3. The next element of the input list is `a = 3`, and `(x,y) = ([2],[1])`, so `(a:y,x) = ([3,1],[2])`.
4. The next element of the input list is `a = 4`, and `(x,y) = ([3,1],[2])`, so `(a:y,x) = ([4,2],[3,1])`.
5. The next element of the input list is `a = 4`, and `(x,y) = ([4,2],[3,1])`, so `(a:y,x) = ([5,3,1],[4,2])`.
6. There are no more elements left, so the return value is `([5,3,1],[4,2])`.

As the walkthrough shows, the split function works by maintaining two lists, swapping them on each iteration, and appending each element of the input to a different list.

Comment: could you also comment on why lazy pattern matching is used in this example?

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_pattern_match discusses the difference between `~(a, b)` and `(a, b)` using `splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` as an example. I think the same (or at least a similar) argument will apply to `split`.

Comment: Basically, if the fold function uses a strict pattern match, it would have to recurse all the way to the end of the list to reach `([], [])` to ensure that there *is* a pair to unpatch. The function with lazy pattern matching is equivalent to `(\a p -> (a:fst p, snd p))`, which doesn't care if `p` is a pair until later.

Answer (score 2):

We can take a look at an example. For example if we have a list `[1, 4, 2, 5]`. If we thus process the list, then we see that `foldr` will be calculated as:

```
foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [1,4,2,5]
```

So here `a` is first the first item of the list, and then it will tus return something like:

```
(1:y, x)
    where (x, y) = foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [4,2,5]
```

Notice that here the `(x, y)` tuple is *swapped* when we prepend `a` to the first item of the 2-tuple.

```
(1:y, x)
    where (x, y) = (4:y', x')
          (x', y') = foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [2,5]
```

and if we keep doing that, we thus obtain:

```
(1:y, x)
    where (x, y) = (4:y', x')
          (x', y') = (2:y'', x'')
          (x'', y'') = (5:y''', x''')
          (x''', y''') = foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) []
```

Since we reached the end of the list, we thus obtain for the `foldr … ([], []) []`, the 2-tuple `([], [])`:

```
(1:y, x)
    where (x, y) = (4:y', x')
          (x', y') = (2:y'', x'')
          (x'', y'') = (5:y''', x''')
          (x''', y''') = ([],[])
```

So `x''' = []` and `y''' = []`, so thus this is resolved to:

```
(1:y, x)
    where (x, y) = (4:y', x')
          (x', y') = (2:y'', x'')
          (x'', y'') = (5:[], [])
          (x''', y''') = ([],[])
```

so `x'' = [5]` and `y'' = []`:

```
(1:y, x)
    where (x, y) = (4:y', x')
          (x', y') = (2:[], [5])
          (x'', y'') = (5:[], [])
          (x''', y''') = ([],[])
```

so `x' = [5]` and `y' = [2]`:

```
(1:y, x)
    where (x, y) = (4:[5], [2])
          (x', y') = (2:[], [5])
          (x'', y'') = (5:[], [])
          (x''', y''') = ([],[])
```

so `x = [4, 5]` and `y = [2]` so eventually we obtain:

```
(1:[2], [4,5])
    where (x, y) = (4:[5], [2])
          (x', y') = (2:[], [5])
          (x'', y'') = (5:[], [])
          (x''', y''') = ([],[])
```

so the result is the expected `([1,2], [4,5])`.

Comment: The result should be `([1,2],[4,5])` i suppose.

Comment: Thanks. One more question: Does this code work with `foldl` instead of `foldr` ? Why ?

Comment: @Michael: the items will be in reversed order, and furthermore depending on the length of the function the first item of the list will be in the first or second item of the 2-tuple.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Approximately,

```
foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [a,b,c,d,e]
=
let g a ~(x,y) = (a:y,x) in
g a $ g b $ g c $ g d $ g e ([],[])
=
g a $ g b $ g c $ g d $ ([e],[])
=
g a $ g b $ g c $ ([d],[e])
=
g a $ g b $ ([c,e],[d])
=
g a $ ([b,d],[c,e])
=
([a,c,e],[b,d])
```

But truly,

```
foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [a,b,c,d,e]
=
let g a ~(x,y) = (a:y,x) in
g a $ foldr g ([],[]) [b,c,d,e]
=
(a:y,x) where 
    (x,y) = foldr g ([],[]) [b,c,d,e]
=
(a:y,x) where 
    (x,y) = (b:y2,x2) where
                 (x2,y2) = foldr g ([],[]) [c,d,e]
=
(a:y,x) where 
    (x,y) = (b:y2,x2) where
                 (x2,y2) = (c:y3,x3) where
                                (x3,y3) = (d:y4,x4) where
                                               (x4,y4) = (e:y5,x5) where
                                                              (x5,y5) = ([],[])
```

which is forced in the *top-down* manner by access (if and when), being progressively fleshed-out as, e.g.,

```
=
(a:x2,b:y2) where 
                 (x2,y2) = (c:y3,x3) where
                                (x3,y3) = (d:y4,x4) where
                                               (x4,y4) = (e:y5,x5) where
                                                              (x5,y5) = ([],[])
=
(a:c:y3,b:x3) where 
                                (x3,y3) = (d:y4,x4) where
                                               (x4,y4) = (e:y5,x5) where
                                                              (x5,y5) = ([],[])
=
(a:c:x4,b:d:y4) where 
                                               (x4,y4) = (e:y5,x5) where
                                                              (x5,y5) = ([],[])
=
(a:c:e:y5,b:d:x5) where 
                                                              (x5,y5) = ([],[])
=
(a:c:e:[],b:d:[])
```

but it could be that the forcing will be done in a different order, depending on how it is called, e.g.

```
print . (!!1) . snd $ foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [a,b,c,d,e]
print . (!!2) . fst $ foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) [a,b,c,d,e]
```

etc.

---

*edit:* to address the questions about the lazy pattern, it is done for proper laziness of the resulting function:

- **`foldr`** with the combining function which is **strict** in its second argument, encodes *recursion*, which is *bottom-up*. The result of recursively processing the rest of the list is constructed first, and the head portion of the result is combined with that, afterwards.
- **`foldr`** with the combining function which is **lazy** in its second argument, encodes *corecursion*, which is *top-down*. The head portion of the resulting value is constructed first, and the rest is filled out later. It is very reminiscent of *tail recursion modulo cons*, in Prolog and elsewhere. Lazy evaluation as a concept came from "`CONS` should not evaluate its arguments"; TRMC does not evaluate the *second* argument to the constructor until later, which is what really matters.

Answer (score 2):

Let's translate the fold away.

```
splatter :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splatter = foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[])
```

What's this mean? `foldr` for lists is defined

```
foldr :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r
foldr k z = go
  where
    go [] = z
    go (p : ps) = p `k` go ps
```

Let's inline it and simplify:

```
splatter = go
  where
    go [] = ([], [])
    go (p : ps) =
      (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) p (go ps)

splatter = go
  where
    go [] = ([], [])
    go (p : ps) =
      (\ ~(x,y) -> (p:y,x)) (go ps)

splatter = go
  where
    go [] = ([], [])
    go (p : ps) =
      let (x, y) = go ps
      in (p : y, x)
```

The lazy-by-default pattern match in the `let` means that we don't actually actually make the recursive call until someone forces `x` or `y`.

The key thing to notice is that `x` and `y` swap places on each recursive call. This leads to the alternating pattern.

Answer (score 1):

So everything happens in the `\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)` function where in first turn `a` is the last item from of the provided list and `(x,y)` is an alternating tuple accumulator that starts with `([],[])`. The current element gets prepended to `y` by `a:y` but then the `x` and `y` lists in tuple gets swapped.

However it's worth to mention that, all new appendings are returned on the first side of the tuple which guarantees the first side eventually starts with the first item of the list since it gets appended the last.

So for a list of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` the steps are follows

```
a          (x   ,   y)      return
----------------------------------
6       ([]     , []     ) (6:y, x)
5       ([6]    , []     ) (5:y, x)
4       ([5]    , [6]    ) (4:y, x)
3       ([4,6]  , [5]    ) (3:y, x)
2       ([3,5]  , [4,6]  ) (2:y, x)
1       ([2,4,6], [3,5]  ) (1:y, x)
[]      ([1,3,5], [2,4,6]) no return
```

Regarding the tilde `~` operator it is best described in the [Haskell/Laziness](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) topic of Haskell guide as follows

> Prepending a pattern with a tilde sign delays the evaluation of the
>   value until the component parts are actually used. But you run the
>   risk that the value might not match the pattern — you're telling the
>   compiler 'Trust me, I know it'll work out'. (If it turns out it
>   doesn't match the pattern, you get a runtime error.) To illustrate the
>   difference:

```
Prelude> let f (x,y) = 1
Prelude> f undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined

Prelude> let f ~(x,y) = 1
Prelude> f undefined
1
```

> In the first example, the value is evaluated because it has to match
>   the tuple pattern. You evaluate undefined and get undefined, which
>   stops the proceedings. In the latter example, you don't bother
>   evaluating the parameter until it's needed, which turns out to be
>   never, so it doesn't matter you passed it undefined.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the code in question uses a lazy pattern, though. It's not trying to protect against a pattern-match failure.

Comment: @chepner Your comment under one of the answers explains it well so people should not overlook that. Then i can not make sure if this has an effect on the performance since either way you have to process the list all the way, right..?

Comment: no, we don't have to process all the list, all the way. if we call `take 2 . fst $ foldr ...`, only the first two elements of the first split will be returned, i.e. only the first *three* positions in the input list's spine will be accessed. but without the `~`, yes, the *whole* list would be accessed, regardless.

Comment: @WillNess `take 2 . fst` is a good point but i can not make sure since the workflow is right to left. Doesn't it have to process all the list all the way in order to find what eventually ends up at the first two positions of the first list in the tuple?

Comment: no. see my answer, under "But truly". e.g. `take 1 . fst` causes just one reduction: `(a:y,x)` is already known after it (with `y`, `x` still unknown) and it is all we need for `take 1` to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the fold function alternates which list the next item from the input list is added to. A similar function in a language like Python would be

```
def split(xs):
    a0 = a = []
    b0 = b = []
    for x in xs:
        a.append(x)
        a, b = b, a
    return a0, b0
```

---

A lazy pattern is used for two reasons:

1. To allow consuming the resulting lists immediately, without waiting for `foldr` to consume all the input
2. To allow splitting of infinite lists.

Consider this example:

```
let (odds, evens) = foldr (\a ~(x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) $ [1..]
in take 5 odds
```

The result is `[1,3,5,7,9]`.

If you dropped the lazy pattern and used

```
let (odds, evens) = foldr (\a (x,y) -> (a:y,x)) ([],[]) $ [1..]
in take 10 odds
```

the code would never terminate, because `take` couldn't get the first element (let alone the first five) without first computing the entire list of odd values.

Why is that? Consider the definition of `Data.List.foldr`:

```
foldr k z = go
  where
    go [] = z
    go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

If `k = \a (x,y) -> (a:y, x)` is strict in both arguments, then the evaluation of `` y `k` go ys `` doesn't terminate until the base case of `go` is reached.

Using a lazy pattern, the function is equivalent to

```
\a p -> (a:snd p, fst p)
```

meaning we never have to match on `p` until `fst` or `snd` does so; the function is now lazy in its second argument. That means that

```
go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
          = (\a p -> (a:snd p, fst p)) y (go ys)
          = let p = go ys in (y:snd p, fst p)
```

returns immediately without further evaluating `go`. Only once we try to get the second element of either list do we need to call `go` again, but once again we only have to progress one step.